# Filling a vector with a custom defined class through pointers - trouble with constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, lambda, iterator

I'm interested in:

- having an std::vector of pointers to an user defined type/class
- filling this vector in the fastest way

I would like to solve this with:

- while + iterators ( a non-C++11 solution )
- for_each iteration + lambda ( a c++11 solution )

Now after reading the documentation I was trying this for the `iterator` part with the `while`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A{
  public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
  private:
    int n;
    double d;
    float f;
    std::string s;
};

int main(){
  std::vector<A*> v(100); // fixed *A to A*
  std::vector<A*>::iterator iter = v.begin(); // fixed *A to A*
  while( iter != v.end() )
  {
    *iter = new A(); // iter = A(); by the way this does not works either // now fixed using new
    ++iter;
  }
  return(0);
}
```

i know that this is trivial but to me it's not, in my understanding iter it's a pointer and needs to be indirected to the real value that it is pointing in the vector; clearly this concept doesn't work this way.

With the lambda and the for_each i just don't get how to use a constructor for a custom defined class because the documentation only talks about generic methods and functions and seems like i can't use a constructor.

How i can build an object with iterators and lambdas ?

Also, there is a faster way to cycle the entire vector when i need to perform the same action all over the place without using the iteration approach with the `while` and the `for_each` or the `for`.

I would like to avoid the copy constructor overhead so i would like to keep all possible solutions using pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work, your asterisks are in the wrong place. It should be `std::vector<A*>`, not `std::vector<*A>`. Also you're trying to assign a temporary object to a pointer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I hate myself :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use `A*` instead of `*A` to create pointers in C++ and second you can't set a pointer to an instance that created in stack using `A()` instead you should create the value on the heap or use address of a variable from stack, so you should have `*iter = new A()`

Comment: That's really same, except that is is a function and should receive an item and initialize it: `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](A*& p) {p = new A();});`

Comment: And know that you shouldn't hate yourself, since you learn a new thing from the best and most powerful language of the world of computer programming :-)

Comment: thanks, but my compiler complains about some missing argument in the square brackets, so p is a reference to a pointer to A ? a pointer to pointer basically ?

Comment: First this is a lambda with no capture, so it need nothing between `[]`, and second it is a reference to a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer and you should know that in C++ references are powerful feature of language, but in implementation yes it is implemented as a pointer and that's a different discussion. For us it is a reference to a pointer and that's all we need!!

Comment: I forgot to add the C++11 flag for my compiler, this is not a good day ... thanks, your solution now works :D